# Error (This table contains cells that are outside the range of cells defined in this spreadsheet) when Reading Excel Data using OleDb in C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I'm a beginner learning C#. I'm trying to read data from an excel file, but I don't know why I keep getting the error:

'This table contains cells that are outside the range of cells defined in this spreadsheet'

I tried the same method previously, and didn't get any error, but that was for a pre-existing excel file. But in this case, I create the excel file first and then only read from it. The thing is when I read from it starting from column-row "A12" onwards.

The main reason why I want to read the column-row starting from A12 is to determine if there are any empty cells, which can be used later to input data; and this processes is to be repeated each time new data is needed to be added into the excel file.I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do.

here is the code:

```
// Initializing C# - Excel Export Method:                     

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application m_excelLoanReceiptWrite = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

// Writing Data to Excel
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Cells[1, 1] = "Loan Receipt";
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Cells[3, 1] = "Name";
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Cells[5, 1] = "ESM ID No.";
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Cells[7, 1] = "Mobile No.";
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Cells[3, 4] = "Loan Date & Time:";
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Cells[5, 4] = "Return Date & Time:";
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Cells[7, 4] = "Venue:";
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Cells[11, 1] = "Recipient's Loan Item List";
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Cells[12, 1] = "No.";
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Cells[12, 2] = "Item Name";
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Cells[12, 3] = "Item Barcode";


//Opening and Saving into Excel File:
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(m_excelLoanReceiptFileFullPath);  //Specifying Excel File Name and Location via textBoxExcelLoanItemTrackerLocation.Text
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;     //check tomake sure excel file has been saved

//Close Excel File after Write and Save process:
m_excelLoanReceiptWrite.Quit();


/*************************** xlswrite sequences to Excel Receipt file for each Loan <ESMID>.xls <End>**********************/



/*************************** Data Extraction from post-written Loan Receipt Excel File <Begin>*****************************/

//Creating a connection directory to access the Excel "LoanItemTracker" file
string m_pathSourceExcelLoanReceipt = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + m_excelLoanReceiptFileFullPath + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";
OleDbConnection m_pathConnectionExcelLoanReceipt = new OleDbConnection(m_pathSourceExcelLoanItemTracker);

/**********************Excel File "LoanReceipt" Numbering Column data Extraction <Begin> *************************/


string m_commandLoanReceiptNumColumn = "SELECT * FROM [A12:A]";   // SELECT * FROM [A12:A] means selecting the entire 'A' column starting from coordinate A12 

DataSet m_loanReceiptNumColumn = new DataSet();

//  Extracting all the Number Column information from the Excel file "LoanReceipt" using the connection directory and the preset excel command for row selection
OleDbDataAdapter m_loanReceiptNumColumnAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(m_commandLoanReceiptNumColumn, m_pathConnectionExcelLoanReceipt);
m_loanReceiptNumColumnAdapter.Fill(m_loanReceiptNumColumn);

DataTable m_loanReceiptNumColumnMatrix;     //    Declare a Table Matrix to save the excel data contained in the variable m_loanReceiptNumColumnMatrix

int m_loanReceiptNumColumnRowCount;         //    Integer variable to count the rows of the matrix variable m_loanReceiptNumColumnMatrix

m_loanReceiptNumColumnMatrix = m_loanReceiptNumColumn.Tables[0];        //  Saving data in m_loanReceiptNumColumn into the Data Table variable m_loanReceiptNumColumnMatrix

m_loanReceiptNumColumnRowCount = m_loanReceiptNumColumnMatrix.Rows.Count;       //  identifying the number of rows in the matrix variable m_loanReceiptNumColumnMatrix


/**********************Excel File "LoanReceipt" Numbering Column data Extraction <End> *************************/
```

Answer (score 1):

When using OleDbConnection with a workbook, you need to have data in every header row and every header column; like a database.

Try this

> If you have empty cells, first fill those with some data to mark the
> empty cells.